# Получить url с помощью $string=file_get_contents

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста, дописать в функцию вывод адреса, того что в `<a></a>`.
Т.е. url адрес и текст ссылки.

```
<?
$string=file_get_contents("https://сайт.ру/iframe.php");
preg_match_all("/<h2?.*>(.*)<\/h2>/", $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $h) print($h."<br/>"); 
?>
```

Сейчас получаю только содержимое `<h2></h2>`

Comment: `'/href="([^"]+)"/'`

Comment: Спасибо! Но я не смог вставить в свой код вашу конструкцию :( да и как выводить не понял.

Comment: Заменив первый аргумент вызова preg_match_all в коде в вашем вопросе на то, что написал я, вы получите список ссылок вместо содержимого заголовков h2.

Comment: Мне нужно получить и заголовок и ссылку   :(

Comment: Попробуйте добавить [mcve] к вашему вопросу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Парсить нерегулярные структуры(html) регулярными выражениями - плохая идея.
Для разбора DOM есть специализированные встроенные [средства](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php).

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://example.ru/iframe.php");
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
  echo $link->nodeValue.': '.$link->getAttribute("href")."<br/>\n";
}
```

[Fiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/zrkt-j7w8)

Для игнора ошибок в HTML можно воспользоваться этой конструкцией:

```
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
```

---

Для поиска текста заголовка в ссылке:

```
echo $link->getElementsByTagName('h2')[0]->nodeValue.': '.$link->getAttribute("href")."<br/>\n";
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Все здорово, но парсит весь текст, а нужно только то, что в `<h2></h2>`

Comment: `$dom->getElementsByTagName('h2')[0]->getElementsByTagName('a')`

Comment: `foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('h2')[0]->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
` ошибка, страница не открывается

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/iiyk-z67h

Comment: не работает - белый экран, у меня php 5.3 может из-за этого?

Comment: fiddle у вас не работает??

Comment: Это http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/iiyk-z67h не работает. HTTP ERROR 500:

Comment: 5.3: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KE2Je.png https://3v4l.org/KKB7e У меня недостаточно данных, чтобы диагностировать вашу проблему.

Comment: Это видимо с контентом связано, вот ссылка из которой нужно данные получить https://e-pay.tv/adverts/iframe.php?aff=102805&color=0a97fc&blocks=3&width=400&type=vertical

Comment: У меня нет ни времени, ни желания делать за вас вашу работу. Вы некорректно ставите задачу. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Извините. С формулировкой у меня тоже плохо, это факт.